# About integer promotion

Tags: c

According to C17 6.3.1.1

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.

Does 'all values' mean whole identifiers in same scope?
Then when some identifiers are with variable which can't be represented by int (such as long long int) in same identifier scope, there are no any promotion for identifiers?

Comment: It has nothing to do with scope or other variables, it's just talking about the possible values of the type.

Comment: example - "all values of unsigned char" means the set { 0, 1, 2, ...., UCHAR_MAX }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does 'all values' mean whole identifiers in same scope?

I'm not sure why you think all identifiers in a scope matter. The integer promotion applies to a *single* item, be it an object (e.g., variable) or expression.

What it's saying is that, if every possible value of this item (already one of the types guaranteed to fit into an `int` or `unsigned int` as per the paragraphs before your quote<sup>(a)</sup>) can be represented by the `int` type, it gets promoted to an `int`. Otherwise it gets promoted to an `unsigned int`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The text states, in full:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and
>     `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Comment: @paxdiable I saw promoted identifiers being used as operand. And I thought operation have something to do with identifier's scope. C17 6.3.1.1 is subclause of Arithmetic operands(6.3.1).